# Forked process never terminates

Tags: bash, debian, benchmark

I'm wanting to run `sysbench` and have the process fork in the background.

When I run the code below. The stress test completes but I never can get back to bash prompt. Note, I only find the first prime of 2 as an example. I am actually testing a larger amount to stress the CPU:

```
sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=2 run &
```

***I have to mask the folder name because I was told to***

I'm wanting to run a stress test but to record the CPU temperature each second while the test is running. I need to run the test for a certain time, say 1000 seconds, then record the CPU temp after the test ends from (1000, 2500] seconds. How can I do this if the forked process never ends?

[image]

Comment: Press `Enter` to redisplay your prompt.

Answer (score 1):

When you started the `sysbench` run in the background, you immediately got a new prompt.  This is evident from your screenshot.

The `sysbench` process running in the background produced output in the terminal before terminating, causing your prompt to be overwritten.

To get a new prompt, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once.

You get the same behavior with `ls -la &`, i.e. you start a utility in the background and that utility overwrites the prompt that you got immediately after starting it.  Again, just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> redisplays the prompt.

If this is a recurring *issue* for you, and if you don't need the terminal for anything else while `sysbench` is running, then simply *don't* start `sysbench` in the background (remove the `&` from the end of the command).

Comment: In Bash, `set -b` should cause termination of background jobs to be notified immediately, rather than waiting until the next prompt (which it does by default to avoid job info popping up in the middle of your foreground work). Best is to use an additional terminal, set -b, start in background, and retain the ability to inspect the job state with top, ps etc.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Probably, yes. However, if you have the luxury of starting any number of terminals, why not run the utility in the _foreground_?

Comment: Two reasons: (a) For an important long-running process, I don't want to lose it just because I hit Ctrl-C while the wrong window had focus. (b) I can use the same terminal for managing that one job, checking its logs, elapsed time and memory usage, without any confusion. Typical example: validating and loading up a client database, I use one terminal per table.